# Symfony2 security allowing all URLs and not blocking anything

Tags: security, symfony

I'm trying to get very basic security in Symfony up and running.  My `security.yml` file has the follow snippet in it.

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/new, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/create, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

However I can still go to the following URL: http://events.local/app_dev.php/event/new  without being authenticated.  Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^/new` doesn't match `/event/new`, since the `^` indicates that `/new` must be the beginning of the path.

Try `^/event/new`, and I think your problem will be fixed.

From http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html:

> Prepending the path with ^ ensures that only URLs beginning with the pattern are matched. For example, a path of simply /admin (without the ^) would correctly match /admin/foo but would also match URLs like /foo/admin.